# Read Json Value using Ajax/Jquery

Tags: json, jquery

I want to read and assign value to a DIV as it is printed on this web service http://abc.com/new2/app/android/get_product_size.php?productID=113

For example get_product_size.php page may return Text or Number.

I have used following code for the same, the problem is its returning 0 Value when i do an alert.. my code is as follows

```
<div class="home%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%"></div>   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
      var productsize = $('.siz').val();
      var id =%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%;
         var AllData="" ;
           var html="";
           //alert(id);
         $.ajax({

                 type: "POST",

                 url: "http://abc.com/new2/app/android/get_product_size.php?productID="+id,
                 data: "{Size:'" + productsize + "'}",
                //data: {},
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: false,
                 cache: true,
                 success: function(msg) {
                 AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                AllData = html.fromhtml(data.d);
               $("#home%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%").html(AllData);
                //42.toFixed(2);
                 },
                 error: AjaxFailed
             });


          function AjaxSucceeded(result) {

          alert(result);
          }
          function AjaxFailed(result) {
              alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
          }

               });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> > AllData = html.fromhtml(data.d);

What is this "data" in your success function ? The success function's signature is

"success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)" ... Try using this one.

Also, you don't have to provide a stringified map like this

data: "{Size:'" + productsize + "'}"

You can just say {"Size" : productSize}.

Comment: In alert result now i got success msg but the value the value is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

at this point in your ajax block:

```
 data: "{Size:'" + productsize + "'}",
```

you should remove the quotes surrounding `productSize`, like this:

```
 data: "{Size:" + productsize + "}",
```

whatever value you put on the other side of that colon will be the value that gets returned when you call `data.Size`